# ASP .NET Web API throw new HttpResponseException always returns 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I´m trying to do this

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); // 401
```

But this always returns 500(Internal server Error).

Example code:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace Gral_WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("[action]")]
        public string GitTest()
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); // 401
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: why are you mixing .net core and classic asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `return StatusCode(401);` instead. You should avoid using exceptions to control the flow of your application.

Do you have any middleware that's intercepting the exception and overriding the status code to 500?

Comment: What is the URI you are using to access your action?

Comment: I´m calling this: http://localhost:59580/GitTest

I´m using swagger and this is my Startup.cs https://codeshare.io/adjoEe

Comment: @MMachado, assuming you're using default routing rules the URI for this action is `/Login/GitTest`.

Comment: There is always some debate about whether an exception should be used in this way. Purest say an exception should be exceptional, but pragmatists use what works best.